# Why is != 0 better than > 0 for unsigned integer comparison?

Tags: gas, optimization

Although I read the gas optimization report, I'm not sure why `!= 0` is better than `> 0` for unsigned integer comparison. Example code is below.

```js
require(numOfRotations > 0, "Empty arrays");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer. The reason `!= 0` is better is the absence of `DUP1(0X80)` and `GT(0X11)`. But this is a regression in gas savings when going from 0.8.12 to 0.8.13.

https://gist.github.com/IllIllI000/bf2c3120f24a69e489f12b3213c06c94

Answer (score 0):

`!= 0` is better than `> 0` for unsigned integer comparison because if you're checking `> 0`, the comparison will be true because unsigned integers will always be non-negative.

Comment: Your answer applies equally to `!=0`. It will be always true when I use `!=0`. I'm just curious why `!=` is more gas efficient. Is there any difference between opcodes? And also there is a problem if it has a minus value when we use `!=` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [picture bellow](https://github.com/crytic/evm-opcodes) with the opcodes every comparison cost `3 gas`. However I don't see something like `LTE`(Less-than or Equal comparison), so I am asuming that operations like `>=`,`<=` would cost `6 gas` because of the two operations `LT/GT` + `EQ` = `6 gas`. But since you are asking for `>`, and not `>=`, in my opinion there is no price difference.

[image]